# How from background app to fill EditText in foreground app?

Tags: android, android-security

Some password managers like LastPass can catch the moment when foreground app has EditText fields, and then can fill these fields.

I thought that apps absolutely isolated one from another, but LastPass can do it.

How do LastPass fill field in another app? Is there any links to android SDK or articles?

Comment: you are asking how 2 apps are comunicating to each other ? if in the first you did an action, in the second will respond to that action ? example the edit text you mentioned?

Comment: @Moudiz Sorry, do not understand your question.

Comment: I was trying to understand what you need. are you asking that 2 applications are communicating to each other ? if 1 app did something the second app respond ?

Comment: I need to understand how to one app could look at UI of another. How does LastPass know that in that time opened app has two EditText views?

Answer (score 1):

I checked list of permissions LastPass asked from users: https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/lastpass-mobile/lastpass-for-android/#h13

The behaviour you see is due to LastPass **bookmarklets** they installed into your default browser. One of them, apparently, is capturing the password for you.

Answering your question - I don't think it's doable(on non-rooted device, at least) for randomly chosen App A and App B, unless one of them is your browser and you have right permissions in another one.